# Symfony dynamically add form input and convert to JSON

Tags: json, symfony

So this is a bit hard to explain.
thing is, I have this entity

```
class TypeParking
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=55)
     */
    private $libelle;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="time", nullable=true)
     */
    private $tempsmax;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    private $jourdebut;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    private $jourfin;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json_array", nullable=true)
     */
    private $heurstravail;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json_array", nullable=true)
     */
    private $exception;
```

and this is my controller:

```
    /**
     * @Route("/new", name="type_parking_new", methods={"GET","POST"})
     */
    public function new(Request $request): Response
    {
        $typeParking = new TypeParking();
        $form = $this->createForm(TypeParkingType::class, $typeParking);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($typeParking);
            $entityManager->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('type_parking_index');
        }

        return $this->render('type_parking/new.html.twig', [
            'type_parking' => $typeParking,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\TypeParking;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class TypeParkingType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('libelle')
            ->add('tempsmax')
            ->add('jourdebut')
            ->add('jourfin')
            ->add('heurstravail')
            ->add('exception')
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => TypeParking::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

See that exception field ? It's type is JSON in the database.
it must contain a name, a starting date, and ending date and starting time and ending time.
like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/8T7Lz.jpg
whenever I press that Plus button I can add another exception field (JQuery).
and when I submit the form this whole exception field gets parsed into a JSON and saved into the databse alongside the rest of the form.
My database: https://i.stack.imgur.com/svO2s.jpg

I've been trying to get this to work for days now and I couldn't do anything.

Comment: could you show us your TypeParkingType class?

Comment: It's nothing special since I couldn't find a way to make exception into 5 separate fields like in the image but I'll add it

Comment: there I added it

Comment: I'm confused, have you checked that your submitted data actually ends up in the exception field? (after the isValid, inside the if block, try `dump($form->getData()); exit;`, just to check that it is indeed in the field. if it's not, how do you generate the fields in the form?

Comment: it gives me this: https://imgur.com/a/XJ5SDEZ

Comment: the data saves just fine, what I want to do is to have the exception field split into name, date start, date end, time start and time end, and when I press submit all of these fields get ingle JSON FORMATand inserted into a single exception field in the databse

Comment: apparently, your jquery generated form doesn't work as expected, since only a string is found in your exception field. doctrine expects an array. if the structure of your exception is always fixed, you probably could fix that by using `->add('exception_name', TextType::class, ['property_path' => 'exception[name]'])` in your form builder for every sub field. this *might* work.

Comment: I'm still a beginner in symfony, and the JQuery inputs aren't that important for now, now I just want to know how to make multiple fields and group them into a single json string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your form type is very very minimalistic. explicitly add (sub)fields for your exception field.

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\TypeParking;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
// don't forget to add the types here!
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;

class TypeParkingType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('libelle')
            ->add('tempsmax')
            ->add('jourdebut')
            ->add('jourfin')
            ->add('heurstravail')
            ->add('exception_name', TextType::class, ['property_path' => 'exception[name]')
            // add other fields of exception, look at 
            // https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types.html
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => TypeParking::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

I hope this helps ...

however, the form component (property accessor) will try to get the exception, so we have to help by adding the following to the TypeParking entity class:

```
public function getException() {
    return array_merge([
        'name' => '', 
        // other sub-fields "empty" values
    ], $this->exception ?? [] // prevent array_merge from failing if exception is empty
    );
}
```

Comment: gives me this error: PropertyAccessor requires a graph of objects or arrays to operate on, but it found type "NULL" while trying to traverse path "exception[name]" at property "name".

Comment: feared as much, you have to help the property accessor find what it's looking for. updated my answer.

Comment: That fixed it thanks a lot for taking the time to answer, I'll try to expand on your answer and see what I can do.