# transforming a set of form inputs into JSON

Tags: json, symfony, frameworks, symfony4

So this is going to sound a bit complicated since I'm a total noob to JSON but bear with me guys, I really need this.
let me start by showing my entity

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\TypeParkingRepository")
 */
class TypeParking
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=55)
     */
    private $libelle;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    private $jourdebut;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    private $jourfin;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json_array", nullable=true)
     */
    private $exception;


    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }



    public function getJourdebut(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->jourdebut;
    }

    public function setJourdebut(\DateTimeInterface $jourdebut): self
    {
        $this->jourdebut = $jourdebut;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getJourfin(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->jourfin;
    }

    public function setJourfin(\DateTimeInterface $jourfin): self
    {
        $this->jourfin = $jourfin;

        return $this;
    }


    public function getException() {
        return array_merge([
            'name' => null,
            'datedebut' => null, 
            'datefin' => null, 
            'heuredebut' => null, 
            'heurefin' => null, 

            // other sub-fields "empty" values
        ], $this->exception ?? [] // prevent array_merge from failing if exception is empty
        );
    }

    public function setException($exception): self
    {
        $this->exception = $exception;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLibelle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->libelle;
    }

    public function setLibelle(string $libelle): self
    {
        $this->libelle = $libelle;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

As you can see I have this property called exception, now this property has many sub properties such as name, datedebut,datefin...
So I had to use JSON format for it.
so I created this formtype called TypeParkingType.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateTimeType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TimeType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;

use App\Entity\TypeParking;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class TypeParkingType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('libelle')
            ->add('tempsmax')
            ->add('jourdebut')
            ->add('jourfin')

            ->add('jourstravail_jour', TextType::class, ['property_path' => 'jourstravail[jour]'])
            ->add('jourstravail_debut', TextType::class, ['property_path' => 'jourstravail[debut]'])
            ->add('jourstravail_fin', TextType::class, ['property_path' => 'jourstravail[fin]'])


            ->add('Exception_Name', TextType::class, ['property_path' => 'exception[name]'])
            ->add('Starting_date', DateTimeType::class, [
                'property_path' => 'exception[datedebut]',
            ])
            ->add('Ending_date', DateTimeType::class, [
                'property_path' => 'exception[datefin]',
            ])
            ->add('Starting_time', TextType::class, ['property_path' => 'exception[heuredebut]'])
            ->add('Ending_time', TextType::class, ['property_path' => 'exception[heurefin]'])

        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => TypeParking::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Sadly this doesn't work because even after inserting the data into the database it does so in a impractical way that's impossible to read.
To make it more complicated, each form can have more than one exception meaning that I have to parse the data in a way like: Ex: {exceptionName(datedebut:...,datefin...,time:...),exceptionname2....}

what I mean by impossible is that it gives me a string like this one https://i.stack.imgur.com/emsYY.jpg which:

1. gives me this error when I go to the edit page for the chosen type: 
   `Unable to transform value for property path "exception[datedebut]": Expected a \DateTimeInterface.`
2. I can't extract the data one by one from it

TL;DR: how can I insert the values related to exception into a single JSON string in the database.

Comment: what does "impractical way" mean? why is it impossible to read? because ... you just - in your code - call `$typeParking->getException()` and get a nice array. last time you didn't ask for multiple exceptions, that would have been different... (assuming Hyperion is you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55430591/symfony-dynamically-add-form-input-and-convert-to-json/55431291)

Comment: hey, yeah actually that was me, (had some problems with google account), well what I mean by impossible is that it gives me a string like this one imgur.com/a/ydYbpaQ which :

Comment: 1- gives me this error when I go to the edit page for the chosen type ('Unable to transform value for property path "exception[datedebut]": Expected a \DateTimeInterface.")

Comment: 2- I can't extract the data one by one from it

Comment: add that to your question please, since is probably a major part of your problem ;o)

Comment: I edited my post :)

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to add a new `ExceptionType` to which you move your exception fields (give it a `data_class` of `null` (essentially: an array).

in your main form:

```
->add('exception', CollectionType::class, [
     'entry_type' => ExceptionType::class,
     // have a look at the other options!
   ]);
```

(see https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html for information on the `CollectionType`)

For your serialization and deserialization problem (this is essentially it), I would propose that you use a data transformer, that you apply to the date field.

it essentially takes a date string '2019-01-02' or whatever and turns it into a DateTime and vice versa. This way, the DateTime that is provided by your form isn't serialized into some object but a string.

see https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html

your CallbackTransformer would look something like:

```
        new CallbackTransformer(
            function (string $string=null) {
                // transform string to DateTime
                return $string ? new \DateTime($string) : null;
            },
            function (\DateTime $datetime=null) {
                // transform the string back to an array
                return $datetime ? $datetime->format('Y-m-d') : null
            }
        )
```

for this to work properly for your existing database entries, you have to remove them or fix manually so that the date string is just YYYY-MM-DD instead of the `{ ... }` and you have to wrap your exceptions so far in '[ ... ]' so that it is an array.

**update**:

of course, due to the changes to exception (now containing multiple exceptions instead of one), you have to change your Entity's getException method:

```
public function getException() {
    return $this->exception ?? [];
}
```

possibly you can drop the whole method ... I'm not quite sure tbh.

Comment: So I created ExceptionType and copied the fields realted to exception there instead, then I went back to TypeParkingType and added ->add('exception', CollectionType::class, [
     'entry_type' => ExceptionType::class,
     // have a look at the other options!
   ]); and finally went to my _form.html.twig and pasted this :    {{ form_row(form.exception, { 'label': 'exception' }) }}
and now the form has every input repeated 5 times

Comment: for a new entry or for an old one? ;o) because the collection type takes your current (old entry) array (which is an exception with 5 fields) and tries to map it to 5 exceptions, which doesn't work so well.

Comment: I want the inputs I placed in ExceptionType to get integrated into my form. like in this pic https://imgur.com/a/in78SIB. Unless I put a button to add another group of inputs (I'm gonna leave this task for later)

Comment: @Nova ah, I understand. The problem is the old TypeParking::getException method. please consider the update.

Comment: Still not working, now it doesn't show any field, I'm working on it, btw since I'm using CollectionType, wouldn't that mean that the data woudn't get transfoemed into a json, but a collection instead, here's how I wanted my data to look like https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVO7Q.png but instead of users it's exceptions...

Comment: @Nova well, the editor theoretically allows for no exceptions to be present. And since there's probably none to begin with ... you have to add some. the CollectionType stores a prototype of the form in its prototype property, in your template you can access it via `{{ form.exception.vars.prototype }}` - it's a form, so you also can call `form_widget` on it. however, since you want to dynamically add exceptions, you should do so. Have a look at https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html#form-collections-new-prototype (and add some jquery or whatever)